# Any match array in value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

*I want to find any match array in input value:*

```js
var vals = new Array('stackoverflow', 'google', 'yahoo');
var val = $('#txtAddress').val();

if ($.inArray(val, vals) != -1) {
  alert('yep');
} else {
  alert('nope');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="txtAddress" type="text" value="google is better" maxlength="100" id="txtAddress">
```

but it's not working, I want tp find any match `array` in `value`, for example `value` is `google is better` and array is `google` but it won't find `google` in this value, only works when value is `google` and array is `google` like this:

```js
var vals = new Array('stackoverflow', 'google', 'yahoo');
var val = $('#txtAddress').val();

if ($.inArray(val, vals) != -1) {
  alert('yep');
} else {
  alert('nope');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="txtAddress" type="text" value="google" maxlength="100" id="txtAddress">
```

so, any solution to find any match array in this value?

**Update:** I also tried this way but not working too:

```js
var vals = new Array('stackoverflow','google','yahoo');
var val = $('#txtAddress').val();
 
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
    if (vals[i] === val) {
        alert('Value exist');
    } else {
        alert('Value does not exist');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="txtAddress" type="text" value="google is better" maxlength="100" id="txtAddress">
```

*And can I alert that matched terms?*

Comment: you are looking for "google is better" in the Array which is not there.

Comment: No, I'm looking for `google` in `google is better` , maybe i did a wrong method , right? @MukundGandlur

Comment: What are your expectations for multiple matches? What are your expectations for tyops? Have you researched this in any way beyond attempting to use an equality comparison?

Comment: Try _.each('stackoverflow','google','yahoo'], alert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the values of array present on the input string(substring). For that, you can use  `indexOf()`.

If the value is not there, it will return -1

```
var vals = new Array('stackoverflow', 'google', 'yahoo');
var val = $('#txtAddress').val();
$.each(vals, function(i, a) {
  if (val.indexOf(a) > -1) {
    alert("found in " + a);
  }

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/214/)

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

$.inArray(val, vals) does not do substring match.
it just compares the value the way you are doing in for loop.

I guess you need substring match to find 'google' in 'google is better'

for that i guess you can:
[How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring)

```
if val[i].indexOf(vals[i]) > -1 then match else not
```